# Postgres Query Solution

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

```
with FQuery as 
(
select ci_nm      as ci_nm 
,     ci_nm             as ci_alias_nm
from rpt.ci_d
),
SQuery as 
(
select ci_nm, ci_alias_nm from FQuery limit 10
)
insert into stg.Test1 (Select * from SQuery),
insert into stg.Test2 Select * from SQuery;
```

I am trying to achieve insert in multiple tables from the second subquery. However, it is giving an error 'ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "insert"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two "main queries". There might be something wrong with your database design if you want to insert same data to two tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make 2 queries at once, you should use [transactions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm).

```
BEGIN;
-- YOUR SQL STUFF
COMMIT;
```